# Create2 contract deploys itself and not the intended contract (solidity)

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Factory {
    // Returns the address of the newly deployed contract
    function deploy(
        address _owner,
        uint _foo,
        uint _salt
    ) public payable returns (address) {
        return address(new TestContract{salt: bytes32(_salt)}(_owner, _foo));
    }
}

contract TestContract {
    address public owner;
    uint public foo;

    constructor(address _owner, uint _foo) payable {
        owner = _owner;
        foo = _foo;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

when I try to deploy the test contract using the factory contract the address I get is of another factory contract and not the test contract.

Can anyone tell me why is it not behaving properly or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The At Address call function on remix is faulty.

It loads the incorrect contract.

I investigated the deployed contract on etherscan and the address was of the intended contract.